# Does NumPy have a Uniformity function?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a NumPy function for this:

[image]

I can calculate it, I'm just wondering if there's a better way.

Here is how I'd calculate it without a given function -

The `len(z_vals)` is substituting for `Ai / A`, because the individual areas are uniformly distributed.

```
ui_minus = 0
for value in z_vals:
    ui_minus += abs(value - np.average(z_vals))/(len(z_vals)*np.average(z_vals))

ui = 1 - 0.5*ui_minus
```

Comment: Please provide some background on the function.

Comment: It's a spatial uniformity function. wi is an individual value, wmean is the average of all of the values. A is the area corresponding to the value....

Comment: @mauve What is the context? While I've seen functions like this before, I've never seen/heard it called a uniformity function.  Does this have to do with atmospheric science?

Comment: It's a flow uniformity. Essentially, it's flow through a 2-D surface. Calculation is to describe how well-distributed the flow is across the surface...we use it for both gas values (ppm...pollutants) and for velocities.

Comment: @mauve You have effectively solved your own problem. If `z_vals` is a 1D array replacing `value` with `z_vales` and removing the python loop will give a vectorized solution. I am not sure what you could want past this.

Comment: @Ophion ... and will bring the complexity down from quadratic to linear (note computation of averages inside the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code bellow is your solution without the loop

```
ui = 1 - 0.5*sum(abs(z_vals - np.average(z_vals)))/(len(z_vals)*np.average(z_vals))
```

If you need to use this calculation very often in your code, you can easily define a function using the method `lambda`

```
uniformity = lambda x : 1 - 0.5*sum( abs(x - np.average(x)) )/(len(x)*np.average(x))
```

Then you can simply call uniformity as shown bellow.

```
ui = uniformity(z_vals)
```

Hope it helps.